# Performance of Windows 8 affected on my PC

Tags: performance, windows-8

I have Eclipse, IBM MQ listener and Oracle Listeners running on my Windows 8. Meanwhile i am trying to copy a 1TB data from other source to my HD. I have seen in windows 8 the popup of copying has an extra feature of showing graphical representation in speed of COPY.

Question: Since in Windows 8 release, there have been heavy bitmaps or some graphical presentations. How is the performance of Windows 8 with the heavy usage applications like ECLIPSE, IBM MQ, ORACLE and copying data like 1TB working simultaneously, remember apart from this AntiVirus is also running. I observed in my pc as slow and hanged, might be the RAM or Processor effect. But what about the performance in windows 8?

Comment: Windows 8 itself is [on par or faster](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/gentlemen-start-your-benches-measuring-windows-8s-performance/) than Windows 7, so debugging your performance issues must go beyond simply what OS you're running, to the nature of how your programs are set up and what they're doing.

Comment: Anvesh, I think the fact that you're copying a 1TB file, and therefore flooding the I/O channel, is far more relevant than the minor CPU hit that a vector-based graphic will have.

Comment: @Sidran32 & Randolph West: I have read in some articles earlier, loading images need more speed. Therefore, in win8 with these activities and developers environment doesn't affect any performance ? I observed win7 and win8 to be same im PC.

Comment: @AnveshVejandla The single biggest reason for performance hits in computing is disk I/O operations. Reading and writing disks are the slowest operation a computer is able to do, and it interrupts all other CPU activity in the process (it's a blocking task). So Randolph is likely correct in his assessment.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, performance is improved in Windows 8. If you are having performance problems, more often than not, you are going to want to update your hardware drivers. This can be accomplished with the Device Manager.

Comment: I understand the performance and speed in Windows8. However, I cannot figure out the relation between windows 7 and windows 8 with the above mentioned applications running at the same time. Can you provide some work or images on performance running in windows 8 with the heavier applications like those